# Unable to add Spotify App Remote SDK library to Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, api, spotify

**EDIT: Added link to instructions**
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/. I am at the section "Add the App Remote SDK".

I am following the step-by-step instructions provided by Spotify to add the App Remote SDK to my Android Studio project.

Their instructions state:

Unzip the App Remote SDK zip file that you downloaded. Add the library to your project by importing it as a module. In the “Project” side bar in Android Studio (View –> Tool Windows –> Project), right click your project’s root folder and navigate to “New” –> “Module”. **In the “New Module” window, choose the option “Import .JAR/AAR Package”. Click “Next”.**

With Android Studio Chipmunk, this option is no longer available.

I have tried numerous ways of importing the folder "android-sdk-0.7.2.-appremote-v1.2.3-auth" as a library into my Android Project. No matter how I do it, the Gradle Sync succeeds, but my code is not able to resolve any of the com.spotify.android imports. For example:

```
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.ConnectionAparams;
```

Why am I having so much trouble importing a library into AS Chipmunk?  I never had problems when using previous versions.

Is anyone else having this issue or just me?

Answer (score 1):

TO fix this problem, I compiled the library into an AAR file. I copied the AAR file to the "libs" folder. Then added it as a module in the Gradle Build.  Not sure why this works, but it does...

Comment: Could you share the exact steps you took to do this? Trying to and failing. Thanks.